UIKit, How to disable toggle item close itself when toggle item clicked by javascript control
I want to use the UIKit toggle the table's  by javascript
work find, but click toggle item  will close itself
I don't want the toggle target close itself when it's clicked, only toggle link or button control the toggle open and close
Codpen Sample
<!doctype html>

<html>

    <body>

        <div id="Test_Table_Div">

            <table id="Test_Table">

                <tr class="A">

                    <td>
                         <a>Link_Click_Toggle</a>
                    </td>

                </tr>

                <tr class="B" hidden>

                    <td>
                        <table> 
                            <tr><td>123</td></tr> 
                            <tr><td>ABC</td></tr> 
                        </table> 
                    </td>

                </tr>

            </table>

        </div>

    </body>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/uikit@3.21.5/dist/js/uikit.min.js"></script>

</html>



$("#Test_Table_Div").on( "click", "#Test_Table tr.A a",  function() {

  UIkit.toggle("#Test_Table_Div #Test_Table tr.B", {  animation: "uk-animation-fade" }).toggle() ;

}) ;



you  need to modify the event handling in JavaScript.
$(document).ready(function() {
                // Attach click event listener to the link inside the first row
                $("#Test_Table_Div").on("click", "#Test_Table tr.A a", function(event) {
                    // Prevent default behavior of the link
                    event.preventDefault();
                    // Toggle the visibility of the second row
                    UIkit.toggle("#Test_Table_Div #Test_Table tr.B", { animation: "uk-animation-fade" }).toggle();
                });

                // Prevent clicks inside the second row from toggling its visibility
                $("#Test_Table_Div").on("click", "#Test_Table tr.B", function(event) {
                    event.stopPropagation();
                });


thanks for reply, the code  with event not work, click toggle item still close itself
